# How to calculate the number of parameters of an LSTM network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

Is there a way to calculate the total number of parameters in a LSTM network.

I have found a example but I'm unsure of how correct [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10615/number-of-parameters-in-an-lstm-model) is or If I have understood it correctly.

For eg consider the following example:-

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_dim=4096, input_length=16))
model.summary()
```

## Output

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                       Output Shape        Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                      (None, 256)         4457472     lstm_input_1[0][0]               
====================================================================================================
Total params: 4457472
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

As per My understanding `n` is the input vector lenght.
And `m` is the number of time steps. and in this example they consider the number of hidden layers to be 1.

Hence according to the formula in [the post.](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10615/number-of-parameters-in-an-lstm-model) `4(nm+n^2)` in my example `m=16`;`n=4096`;`num_of_units=256`

```
4*((4096*16)+(4096*4096))*256 = 17246978048
```

Why is there such a difference? 
Did I misunderstand the example or was the formula wrong ?

Comment: Refer to this link if you needed some visual help:
http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10615/number-of-parameters-in-an-lstm-model

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No - the number of parameters of a LSTM layer in Keras equals to:

```
params = 4 * ((size_of_input + 1) * size_of_output + size_of_output^2)
```

Additional `1` comes from bias terms. So `n` is size of input (increased by the bias term) and `m` is size of output of a LSTM layer.

So finally :

```
4 * (4097 * 256 + 256^2) = 4457472
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. Could you also add the source

Comment: Thanks!  I was trying to derive this, and just couldn't figure out what inserted that missing "+1" term.

Comment: So if I'm not wrong the input_length as no effect on the parameters as the same weight matrix would be reused for 1 or 100 time steps  ??

Comment: @ArsenalFanatic, image the complexity of the model would increase with the amount of data you have available. This would not be scalable, from a usability perspective. (I'm only answering, because in the beginning I also thought that the number of timesteps is important ;) ).

Comment: Can you explain why the formula has 4 coefficient and why we take the square of the number of neurons (size of output)?

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947079 I made some error applying this formula. Could you take a look?

Comment: I also want to know why 4

Comment: @Worthy7 it's 4 because LSTM has 4 gates, in case of GRU, it will be 3, in case of vanilla RNN, it will be 1

Comment: What about bidirectional LSTM?

Answer (score 27):

[image]
[image via this post](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)

```
num_params = [(num_units + input_dim + 1) * num_units] * 4
```

**num_units + input_dim:**  concat [h(t-1), x(t)]

**+ 1:** bias

*** 4:** there are 4 neural network layers (yellow box) {W_forget, W_input, W_output, W_cell}

```
model.add(LSTM(units=256, input_dim=4096, input_length=16))
```

[(256 + 4096 + 1) * 256] * 4 = 4457472

PS: num_units = num_hidden_units = output_dims

Comment: Thanks. I found this to be the best explained and most helpful answer. Appreciated the PS and the C. Olah reference.

Answer (score 12):

I think it would be easier to understand if we start with a simple RNN.

Let's assume that we have 4 units (please ignore the ... in the network and concentrate only on visible units), and the input size (number of dimensions) is 3:

[image]

The number of weights is 28 = 16 (`num_units * num_units`) for the recurrent connections + 12 (`input_dim * num_units`) for input. The number of biases is simply `num_units`.

Recurrency means that each neuron output is fed back into the whole network, so if we unroll it in time sequence, it looks like two dense layers:

[image]

and that makes it clear why we have `num_units * num_units` weights for the recurrent part.

The number of parameters for this simple RNN is 32 = 4 * 4 + 3 * 4 + 4, which can be expressed as `num_units * num_units + input_dim * num_units + num_units` or `num_units * (num_units + input_dim + 1)`

Now, for LSTM, we must multiply the number of of these parameters by 4, as this is the number of sub-parameters inside each unit, and it was nicely illustrated in the answer by @FelixHo

Answer (score 8):

Formula expanding for [@JohnStrong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2046923/john-strong) :

**4** means we have different weight and bias variables for **3 gates** (read / write / froget) and - 4-th - for the **cell state** (within same hidden state).
(These mentioned are shared among timesteps along particular hidden state vector)

```
4 * lstm_hidden_state_size * (lstm_inputs_size + bias_variable + lstm_outputs_size)
```

as LSTM output (**y**) is **h** (hidden state) by approach, so, without an extra projection, for LSTM outputs we have :

```
lstm_hidden_state_size = lstm_outputs_size
```

let's say it's d :

```
d = lstm_hidden_state_size = lstm_outputs_size
```

Then

```
params = 4 * d * ((lstm_inputs_size + 1) + d) = 4 * ((lstm_inputs_size + 1) * d + d^2)
```

Answer (score 4):

LSTM Equations (via deeplearning.ai Coursera)

[image]

It is evident from the equations that the final dimensions of all the 6 equations will be same and      **final dimension must necessarily be equal to the dimension of a(t)**.

Out of these 6 equations, only 4 equations contribute to the number of parameters and by      looking at the equations, it can be deduced that all the 4 equations are symmetric. So,if we find      out the number of parameters for 1 equation, we can just multiply it by 4 and tell the total number      of parameters.

One important point is to note that the total number of parameters doesn't depend on the      time-steps(or input_length) as same "W" and "b" is shared throughout the time-step.

Assuming, insider of LSTM cell having just one layer for a gate(as that in Keras).

Take equation 1 and lets relate. Let number of neurons in the layer be **n** and number of      dimension of x be **m** (not including number of example and time-steps). Therefore, dimension of      forget gate will be **n** too. Now,same as that in ANN, dimension of "Wf" will be n*(n+m) and      dimension of "bf" will be n. Therefore, total number of parameters for one equation will be       **[{n*(n+m)} + n]**. Therefore, total number of parameters will be 4*[{n*(n+m)} + n].Lets open the      brackets and we will get -> **4*(nm + n<sup>2</sup> + n)**.

So,as per your values. Feeding it into the formula gives:->(n=256,m=4096),total number of      parameters is 4*((256*256) + (256*4096) + (256) ) = 4*(1114368) = 4457472.

Answer (score 0):

The others have pretty much answered it. But just for further clarification, on creating an LSTM layer. The number of params is as follows:

No of params= 4*((num_features used+1)*num_units+
num_units^2)

The +1 is because of the additional bias we take.

Where the num_features is the num_features in your input shape to the LSTM:
Input_shape=(window_size,num_features)