# Number of parameters for Keras SimpleRNN

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I have a `SimpleRNN` like:

```py
model.add(SimpleRNN(10, input_shape=(3, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear"))
```

The model summary says:

```
simple_rnn_1 (SimpleRNN)   (None, 10)   120
```

I am curious about the parameter number `120` for `simple_rnn_1`.

Could you someone answer my question?

Answer (score 12):

When you look at the headline of the table you see the title `Param`:

```
Layer (type)              Output Shape   Param 
===============================================
simple_rnn_1 (SimpleRNN)   (None, 10)    120
```

This number represents the number of trainable parameters (weights and biases) in the respective layer, in this case your `SimpleRNN`.

**Edit:**

The formula for calculating the weights is as follows:

> *recurrent_weights + input_weights + biases*
>
> *resp: (num_features + num_units)* num_units + num_units

**Explanation:**

***num_units*** = equals the number of units in the RNN

***num_features*** = equals the number features of your input

Now you have two things happening in your RNN.

First you have the recurrent loop, where the state is fed recurrently into the model to generate the next step. Weights for the recurrent step are:

***recurrent_weights*** =  num_units*num_units

The secondly you have new input of your sequence at each step.

***input_weights*** = num_features*num_units

(Usually both last RNN state and new input are concatenated and then multiplied with one single weight matrix, nevertheless inputs and last RNN state use different weights)

So now we have the weights, whats missing are the biases - for every unit one bias:

***biases*** = num_units*1

So finally we have the formula:

***recurrent_weights*** + **input_weights** + **biases**

or

*num_units* num_units + num_features* num_units + biases*

=

*(num_features + num_units)* num_units + biases*

In your cases this means the trainable parameters are:

**10*10 + 1*10 + 10 = 120**

I hope this is understandable, if not just tell me - so I can edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: My question was how the number 120 comes. Thanks

Comment: HI, I have one more question. Is it many-to-one type? I mean we use model.add(Dense(1)) after simpleRNN(10, input_shape=(3,1)). Does this means that after look at the third data, the model generate one output using Dense(1) from 10 outputs of the simpleRNN?

Comment: This is bit off-topic, but yes, it's many to one. But 10 units does not mean it produces a sequence of length 10, this is just the dimensionality - the higher the more information you can store, but it's still only one output. If you want to use many to many you need to set `return_sequences=True` in the RNN. The number of `Dense` units in the last layer is usually considered as number of classes and not outputs of a sequence. If you want to know more about `return_sequences` here is a blog post about it: https://machinelearningmastery.com/return-sequences-and-return-states-for-lstms-in-keras/

Comment: @MBT Can you please explain more. I could not understand.

Comment: Both recurrent term and input term have independent biases repectively, so there are two biases in total. Hence, the number of parameters is 10*10 + 1*10 + 10 +10 = 130. Am I right ?

Answer (score 7):

It might be easier to understand visually with a simple network like this:

[image]

The number of weights is 16 (4 * 4) + 12 (3 * 4) = 28 and the number of biases is 4.

where 4 is the number of units and 3 is the number of input dimensions, so the formula is just like in the first answer: `num_units ^ 2 + num_units * input_dim + num_units` or simply `num_units * (num_units + input_dim + 1)`, which yields 10 * (10 + 1 + 1) = 120 for the parameters given in the question.

Comment: i do not understand this graphical representation .

Comment: You might also look at a similar answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080035/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-parameters-of-an-lstm-network/56614978#56614978, hopefully it will make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I visualize the SimpleRNN you add, I think the figure can explain a lot.

[SimpleRNN layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1wB8.jpg), I'm a newbie here, can't post images directly, so you need to click the link.

From the unrolled version of SimpleRNN layer，it can be seen as a dense layer. And the previous layer is a concatenation of input and the current layer(previous step) itself.

So the number of parameters of SimpleRNN can be computed as a dense layer:

**num_para = units_pre * units + num_bias**

where:

**units_pre** is the sum of input neurons（1 in your settings） and **units**(see below),

**units** is the number of neurons（10 in your settings） in the current layer,

**num_bias** is the number of bias term in the current layer, which is the same as the **units**.

Plugging in your settings, we achieve the **num_para** = (1 + 10) * 10 + 10 = 120.