# Number of parameters in Keras deep learning network

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

Anyone knows how to interpret column *param* and its values from function `print(model.summary())`?
Have you find out any links, where this is clearly explained?
[image]

Comment: You can also take a look here, it's about RNNs, not CNNs but maybe still useful for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50134334/number-of-parameters-for-keras-simplernn/50134699#50134699

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The param # column indicates the number of parameters that the particular layer has. For example, your dense_9 layer has 64 units, and the input has 3136 elements.

The number of params are given by the total number of elements in the weights matrix plus the elements in the biases matrix (because it's a dense layer).

You have that 64 * 3136 + 64 = 200768, exactly the value in param #.

If you check the value of param # for the next layer (activation_19) you will see that there aren't any parameters, because activations usually are not parametrized (they have a fixed formula for calculating them)