# Why are the number of parameters 10 in SimpleRNN?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

This was my python code:

```
 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
 from tensorflow.keras.layers import SimpleRNN

 Model = Sequential([
      SimpleRNN(2, input_shape=(2,2))
 ])

 print(Model.summary())
```

The output was:

```
Model: "sequential_23"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
simple_rnn_10 (SimpleRNN)    (None, 2)                 10        
=================================================================
Total params: 10
Trainable params: 10
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

I don't understand why the Number of parameters is 10.

Comment: This question is not about programming, but about how RNNs are built and parameters are defined. I think you'll get better answers at stats.SE or datascience.SE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of parameters for Keras SimpleRNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50134334/number-of-parameters-for-keras-simplernn)

Answer (score 1):

A simple recurrent layer is defined by:

[image]

In your code, you have specified `input_shape=(2,2)` which indicates `|x|=2`. You also set `|h|=2` and have no output layer definied. This leads to the following model:

[image]

Since everything is fully connected in the feed-forward input (black connections) and recurrent input (blue connections), you get 2x2 matrices (weight shape in orange). The bias is a single value that is fully connected to each `h` unit, i.e. there is one weight per unit (in total 2, see green connections).

So in summary:

`W_xh` is the input matrix: 2x2=4 parameters

`W_hh` is the recurrent matrix: 2x2=4 parameters

`b_h` is the bias: 2 parameters

So in total, you have 10 parameters.

Comment: Can you please show with a diagram. It would be much more helpful and understandable with a diagram.