# Keras: Understanding the number of trainable LSTM parameters

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have run [a Keras LSTM demo](https://github.com/ahstat/deep-learning/blob/48aaa17827dfa3ebd13d320f9ba3fb2f3c68f934/rnn/4_lagging_and_stateful.py) containing the following code (after line 166):

```
m = 1
model=Sequential()
dim_in = m
dim_out = m
nb_units = 10

model.add(LSTM(input_shape=(None, dim_in),
                    return_sequences=True, 
                    units=nb_units))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(activation='linear', units=dim_out)))
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'rmsprop')
```

When I prepend a call to `model.summary()`, I see the following output:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, None, 10)          480       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_4 (TimeDist (None, None, 1)           11        
=================================================================
Total params: 491
Trainable params: 491
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I understand that the 11 params of the time distributed layer simply consist of `nb_units` weights plus one bias value.

Now for the LSTM layer:
[These](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38086903/1389680) [answers](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/27067/42614) say:

```
params = 4 * ((input_size + 1) * output_size + output_size^2)
```

In my case with `input_size = 1` and `output_size = 1` this yields only 12 parameters for each of the 10 units, totaling to 120 parameters. Compared to the reported 480, this is off by a factor of 4. Where is my error?

Answer (score 1):

The `params` formula holds for the whole layer, not per Keras unit.

Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44277785/1389680):

> [In Keras], the unit means the dimension of the inner cells in LSTM.
>
> LSTM in Keras only define exactly one LSTM block, whose cells is of unit-length.

Directly setting `output_size = 10` ([like in this comment](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10615/number-of-parameters-in-an-lstm-model/27067#comment39272_27067)) correctly yields the 480 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your error lies in the interpretation of terms given on your quoted page (which is admittedly misleading). So *n* in the reference corresponds to your *nb_units*, which can be appreciated by the fact that this variable enters quadratically into the given formula, and thus corresponds to the recurrent connectivity, which plays out between the *nb_units* LSTM cells only.

So, setting *output_size = n = 10* in your formula above for *params* will give the desired 480 parameters.