# LSTM in Keras: Number of parameters differs between sequential and functional API

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

**With the Sequential API**

If I create a LSTM with the Sequential API of Keras with the following code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(2, input_dim=3))
```

then

```
model.summary()
```

returns **48** parameters, which is OK as indicated in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080035/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-parameters-of-an-lstm-network).

[image: model.summary() with the Sequential API]

*Quick details:*

```
input_dim = 3, output_dim = 2
n_params = 4 * output_dim * (output_dim + input_dim + 1) = 4 * 2 * (2 + 3 + 1) = 48
```

**With the Functional API**

But if I do the same with the functional API with the following code:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import LSTM

inputs = Input(shape=(3, 1))
lstm = LSTM(2)(inputs)
model = Model(input=inputs, output=lstm)
```

then

```
model.summary()
```

returns **32** parameters.

[image: model.summary() with the Functional API]

Why there is such a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that when you pass `input_dim=x` to a RNN layer, including LSTM layers, it means that the input shape is `(None, x)` i.e. there are varying number of timesteps where each one is a vector of length `x`. However, in the functional API example, you are specifying `shape=(3, 1)` as input shape and it means there are 3 timesteps where each has one feature. Therefore the number of parameters would be: `4 * output_dim * (output_dim + input_dim + 1) = 4 * 2 * (2 + 1 + 1) = 32` which is the number shown in the model summary.

Further, if you use Keras 2.x.x, you would get a warning in case of using `input_dim` argument for a RNN layer:

> UserWarning: The `input_dim` and `input_length` arguments in recurrent
>   layers are deprecated. Use `input_shape` instead.
>
> UserWarning: Update your `LSTM` call to the Keras 2 API: `LSTM(2, input_shape=(None, 3))`

Comment: If, in the Functional API, I replace **inputs = Input(shape=(3, 1))** by **inputs = Input(shape=(1, 3))**, I get **48** parameters, as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like the following:

```
Case 1:
m (input) = 3
n (output) = 2

params = 4 * ( (input * output) + (output ^ 2) + output)
       = 4 * (3*2 + 2^2 + 2)
       = 4 * (6 + 4 + 2)
       = 4 * 12
       = 48



Case 2:
m (input) = 1
n (output) = 2

params = 4 * ( (input * output) + (output ^ 2) + output)
       = 4 * (1*2 + 2^2 + 2)
       = 4 * (2 + 4 + 2)
       = 4 * 8
       = 32
```