# Parameters computation of LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to compute the total parameters of LSTM model, and I have some confusion.

I have searched some answers, such as [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10615/number-of-parameters-in-an-lstm-model) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080035/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-parameters-of-an-lstm-network). I don't know how what's the role of hidden units play in the parameter computation(h1=64, h2=128 in my case).

```
import tensorflow as tf

b, t, d_in, d_out = 32, 256, 161, 257

data = tf.placeholder("float", [b, t, d_in])  # [batch, timestep, dim_in]
labels = tf.placeholder("float", [b, t, d_out])  # [batch, timestep, dim_out]

myinput = data
batch_size, seq_len, dim_in = myinput.shape

rnn_layers = []

h1 = 64
c1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(h1)
rnn_layers.append(c1)

h2 = 128
c2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(h1)
rnn_layers.append(c2)

multi_rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(rnn_layers)
rnnoutput, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=multi_rnn_cell, 
inputs=myinput, dtype=tf.float32)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

all_trainable_vars = tf.reduce_sum([tf.reduce_prod(v.shape) for v in tf.trainable_variables()])
print(sess.run(all_trainable_vars))
```

I printed the total number of parameters using Tensorflow, it showed the total number of a parameter is 90880. How can I get this result step by step, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you defined a LSTM cell via this line `c1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(h1)`. To answer your question, here I will introduce the mathematical definition of LSTM. Like the picture (picture source [wikipedia-lstm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LSTM)) below,

[image: LSTM]

`t`: means at time `t`.

- `f_t` is named forget gate．
- `i_t` is named input gate．
- `o_t` is named are called．
- `c_t, h_t` are named the cell state and hidden state of the LSTM cell, respectively.

For `tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(h1)`, `h1=64` is the dimension of `h_t`, i.e. `dim(h_t) = 64`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. One more thing, do you know how can I get the final result 90880? I mean, what are the dimensions of W, U, b for the two layers(h1=64, h2=128)?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake.    c2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(h1). It should be c2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(h2). In my case, for the first later, total parameter: 4 * (64 * (64 + 161) + 64) = 57856, and for the second layer, total parameter: 4 * (128 * (128 + 64) + 128) = 98816. Toally, 57856 + 98816 = 156672, which is as same as what Tensorflow printed.