# Why are these LSTM parameter counts different?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm

I'm building an LSTM, for a report, and would like to summarize things about it. However, I've seen two different ways to build an LSTM in Keras that yield two different values for the number of parameters.

I'd like to understand why the parameters differ in this way.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080035/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-parameters-of-an-lstm-network) question correctly shows why this code

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_dim=4096, input_length=16))
model.summary()
```

results in 4457472 parameters.

From what I can tell, the following two LSTMs should be the same

```
m2 = Sequential()
m2.add(LSTM(1, input_dim=5, input_length=1))
m2.summary()

m3 = Sequential()
m3.add(LSTM((1),batch_input_shape=(None,5,1)))
m3.summary()
```

However, the `m2` results in `28` parameters, but the `m3` results in `12` parameters. **Why?**

How is 12 being calculated for a 1 unit LSTM with a 5-dim input?
*Included the warning message. Hope it is helpful.*

**Output**

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 256)               4457472   
=================================================================
Total params: 4,457,472
Trainable params: 4,457,472
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "difparam.py", line 11
    m2.add(LSTM(1, input_dim=5, input_length=1))
UserWarning: The `input_dim` and `input_length` arguments in recurrent layers are deprecated. Use `input_shape` instead.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "difparam.py", line 11
    m2.add(LSTM(1, input_dim=5, input_length=1))
UserWarning: Update your `LSTM` call to the Keras 2 API: `LSTM(1, input_shape=(1, 5))`
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 1)                 28        
=================================================================
Total params: 28
Trainable params: 28
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 1)                 12        
=================================================================
Total params: 12
Trainable params: 12
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**m2** was built based on info from the Stack Overflow question, and **m3** was built based on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMIWee_PXl8) from YouTube.

Comment: `m2` seems to say 4 x ((1 x 5) + (1^2)+ 1) = 4 x (1 + 5 + 1) = 4 x 7 = 28.
`m3`makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Because the correct values are `input_dim = 1` and `input_length = 5`.

---

It's even written in the warning you received, where the input shape for `m2` is different from the one used in `m3`:

> UserWarning: Update your `LSTM` call to the Keras 2 API: `LSTM(1, input_shape=(1, 5))`

It's highly recommended that you use the suggestion in the warning.

Comment: Okay `m3.add(LSTM((1),batch_input_shape=(None,1,5)))` give the same parameters as `m2.add(LSTM(1, input_dim=5, input_length=1))`. The warning was to cryptic for me.

Comment: This is bad. You don't gain anything from an LSTM with length = 1.

Comment: Right. The points was to understand the param discrepancy. `input_length` is actually optional. In `m3`, the `None` actually represents the input length (i.e. # of observations). It's not a value relevant to parameters. I'm trying to understand param counts beforehand as bad way of comparing to other NN types.

Comment: No, in `batch_input_shape=(None, 1, 5)` the length is 1 -> `batch_input_shape = (samples, length, features)`.